# How to use $push in mongodb?

Tags: php, mongodb

Hi all i am trying to  push values to existing record using $push but i am getting error stating that

```
Invalid modifier specified: $push
```

I am using php below is my code php code

```
$collection->update(array('_id'=>3,"data._id"=>2),array('$push'=>array('userid','52'))); 
i.e adding 52 to userid. In 3 record and data._id 2
```

below is my table structure for mongo db

```
{ "_id" : 2,
  "name" : "test", 
  "data" :[{"_id" : "1",
            "file" : "nic",
            "userid" : [1,2 ]
           },
           {"_id" : "2",
            "file" : "nic1",
            "userid" : [1 ] 
           },
           {"_id" : 3,
            "file" : "nick2",
            "userid" : [1,2 ]
            } 
         ]},

{ "_id" : 3,
  "name" : "test",
  "data" : [{"_id" : "1",
             "file" : "nic",
             "userid" : [1,2 ] 
            },
            {"_id" : "2",
             "file" : "nic1",
             "userid" : [3,2 ] 
            } 
          ]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **[`$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_)** positional operator in your update that identifies an element in the `data` array to update without explicitly specifying the position of the element:

```
$collection -> update(
    array('_id' => 3, "data._id" => 2),
    array('$push' =>
        array('data.$.userid' => 52)
    )
);
```

Comment: Check the data type of `_id` in the the update method, they need to match with the actual data type in the database.

Comment: yep i checked it when i try  this `$collection->find(array('_id' => 3, "data._id" => '2'));` i am able to get values

Comment: thanks for help i modified query it works `array('data.$.userid'=> 52)`

Comment: could you help me with this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33143234/mongodb-multi-nested-array-search)