# Mongodb multi nested array search

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

My aim is to search records of data userid 1

Below is my data

```
{ "_id" : 2,
  "name" : "test", 
  "data" :[{"_id" : "1","file" : "nic", "userid" : [1,2 ]},
           {"_id" : "2","file" : "nic1","userid" : [1 ]  },
           {"_id" : 3,"file" : "nick2","userid" : [1,2 ]} 
     ]},

{ "_id" : 3,
  "name" : "test",
  "data" : [{"_id" : "1","file" : "nic","userid" : [1,2 ]  },
            {"_id" : "2","file" : "nic1", "userid" : [3,2 ] } 
      ]}
```

out put should be

```
{ "_id" : 2,
  "name" : "test", 
  "data" :[{"_id" : "1","file" : "nic", "userid" : [1,2 ]},
           {"_id" : "2","file" : "nic1","userid" : [1 ]  },
           {"_id" : 3,"file" : "nick2","userid" : [1,2 ]} 
     ]},

{ "_id" : 3,
  "name" : "test",
  "data" : [{"_id" : "1","file" : "nic","userid" : [1,2 ]  },          
      ]}
```

I tried

```
$res=$collection->find(array("data.userid" =>array('$in'=>array('52'))));
```

returning null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the [`.aggregate()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) method in order to "filter" any array content for more than a singular match, and also the basic match is a lot simplier as MongoDB does not care that the data is within arrays, just as long as the specified path is correct:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "data.userid": 1 } },
    { "$project": {
        "data": {
            "$setDifference": [
                { "$map": {
                    "input": "$data",
                    "as": "el",
                    "in": { 
                        "$cond": [
                            { "$setIsSubset": [ [1], "$$el.userid" ] },
                            "$$el",
                            false
                        ]
                    }
                }},
                [false]
            ]
        }
    }},
    { "$match": { "data.0": { "$exists": true } }}
])
```

With PHP this notates as follows:

```
$collection->aggregate(array(
    array( '$match' => array( "data.userid" => 1 )),
    array(
        '$project' => array(
            'data' => array(
                '$setDifference' => array(
                    array(
                        '$map' => array(
                            'input' => '$data',
                            'as' => 'el',
                            'in' => array(
                                '$cond' => array(
                                    array( '$setIsSubset' => array(array(1),'$$el.userid') ),
                                    '$$el',
                                    FALSE
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    ),
                    array(FALSE)
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    array( '$match' => array( 'data.0' => array( '$exists' => TRUE ) ) )
))
```

The [**`$map`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) operator allows inspection of each element ofthe outer array and passed each element to the [**`$cond`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) ternary operation. This processes a [**`$setIsSubset`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/) operation on the "inner" array to see if it in fact contains one of the values in the alternate set ( in this case `[1]` ) and where a `true` evaluation is made then the element is returned or otherwise `false`.

The point of [**`$setDifference`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/) is to remove those `false` values from the modified array and only return matched elements. And finally the [**`$exists`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) test looks to see that outer array actually has at least one element and is not empty as a result of the filtering.

The documents returned are the ones with the matching condition and only the array elements that also match the specified condition.

Of course the operators here require that you have at least MongoDB 2.6 as the server ( which is quite an old release now and an advised update at least ) but if you still have a lesser version then you need a traditional approach with [`$unwind`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and [`$group`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/):

```
$collection->aggregate(array(
    array( '$match' => array( "data.userid" => 1 )),
    array( '$unwind' => '$data' ),
    array( '$match' => array( 'data.userid' => 1 )),
    array( 
        '$group' => array(
            '_id' => '$_id',
            'data' => array( '$push' => '$data' )
        )
    )
))
```

Comment: getting error `exception: invalid operator '$setDifference'`

Comment: @sasikanth That means that you have quite an old version of MongoDB ( less than 2.6 ) which does not have those operators. There is an alternate ( and not as performant ) method to this that works in all versions. MongoDB 2.6 is a few years old now and there are many reasons why an upgrade should be considered.

Comment: thanks for helping . I will update my version and check that  once. I need one more help. I want to display all records in data as loop how can i do that

Comment: @sasikanth Please don't update your question as this is an anwer to the question that was asked. If you have addtional questions then [Ask Another Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: blake could you check this lick once [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33174252/mongodb-multi-nested-array-addtoset-push-pull](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33174252/mongodb-multi-nested-array-addtoset-push-pull)