# Mongodb multi array to individual array on search

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

My aim is to create inner array to main array when search for userid as 1
Below is my data

```
{ "_id" : 2,
  "name" : "test1", 
  "data" :[{"_id" : "1","file" : "nic", "userid" : [1,2 ]},
           {"_id" : "2","file" : "nic1","userid" : [1 ]  },
           {"_id" : 3,"file" : "nick2","userid" : [1,2 ]} 
 ]},

{ "_id" : 3,
  "name" : "test2",
  "data" : [{"_id" : "1","file" : "nic","userid" : [1,2 ]  },
            {"_id" : "2","file" : "nic1", "userid" : [3,2 ] } 
  ]}
```

need to get out put as

```
{"_id" : 1,"file" : "nic", "userid" : [1,2 ],"main_name" : "test1","main_id" : 2},
{"_id" : 2,"file" : "nic1","userid" : [1 ] ,"main_name" : "test1","main_id" : 2 },
{"_id" : 3,"file" : "nick2","userid" : [1,2 ],"main_name" : "test2","main_id" : 3},
{"_id" : 1,"file" : "nic","userid" : [1,2 ] ,"main_name" : "test2" ,"main_id" : 3}
```

Comment: What's the question again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the same answer to your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33143234/5031275), but without the [`$group`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) to reconstruct the array and use a [`$project`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) instead to restructure the document from the already de-normalized array elements.

```
$collection->aggregate(array(
    array( '$match' => array( "data.userid" => 1 )),
    array( '$unwind' => '$data' ),
    array( '$match' => array( 'data.userid' => 1 )),
    array(
        '$project' => array(
            '_id' => '$data._id',
            'nic' => '$data.nic',
            'user_id' => '$data.user_id',
            'main_name' => '$name',
            'main_id' => '$_id'
        )
    )
))
```

Comment: same thing if i want to get all records irrespective of userid.how can we do that

Comment: @sasikanth Well "same thing" if you have other questions then [Ask Another Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) ( which is how it works here as this is not a discussion board or forum, but a Question and Answer resource, so you need to ask a singular clear question ). As well it is not clear what you are asking without that, as mostly your whole point so far is all about "filtering" the results by that said "userid" value. So why not just remove the `$match` statements if you just want everything? Or ask another question instead. That is what questions are for,